# How to send table row data to form input for edit in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I need help with angularjs code. The thing is, in my table rows I have "Edit" button, so if I click on edit a row I want the row data shown in a form below for edit. Please how do I complete the Angularjs code to make this work. I included some codes.

HTML

```html
<div ng-controller="nerDev as div1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>S/N</th>
            <th>FName</th>
            <th>LName</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="mywrk in employees | filter:search">
            <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{mywrk.fname}}</td>
            <td>{{mywrk.lname}}</td>
            <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                ng-model="row.clk" ng-click="EditRow()" value="Edit"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class='col-sm-12'>
    <form method="post" novalidate autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>FName:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control"
                ng-model="edit.fname" ng-required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>LName</label> <input type="text" class="form-control"
                ng-model="edit.lname" ng-required="true">
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" value="Update">
        <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" value="Cancel">
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource' ]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$filter', function ($scope, $filter){

  $scope.employees = [
    { 'fname': 'Kelly', 'lname': 'Bob'},
    { 'fname': 'Jay', 'lname': 'White'}
  ];

}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your edit button, just pass your object to your function like this

```
ng-click="EditRow(mywrk)"
```

then in you controller, just add that function and assign the object you've passed to your `$scope.edit` object like this

```
$scope.edit = {}; //you need to initialize this first to prevent error
$scope.EditRow = function(item) {
  $scope.edit = item;
}
```

And you're done.

Comment: @BillP Woa my bad I didn't notice that. Thanks for the head's up.

Comment: @JkAlombro thanks, the code works but i'm still having a problem. The data is not showing on my the form, but when i logged it on the console it worked. Please could you help me on why the data not showing on the form for edit? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

@JKAlombro answer is one way.  Another way, you can get it by `$index`.

- In button click event, you need pass row index

  `ng-click="EditRow($index)"`
- in controller side

  `$scope.edit = {};
  $scope.EditRow = function(index) {
  $scope.edit = $scope.employees[index];
  }`

Comment: Thanks, I used the above method.